# Error while using multi line brackets

Tags: arrays

I am getting a correct output for the below code but latex throws an error

```
**Illegal character in array arg. \begin{array}{11}** along with it.
```

Anybody knows how to fix this error?

```
\begin{equation}
C_1 = \{\beta_{1,1}, \beta_{2,1}\} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\left[
\begin{array}{11}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{11}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{11}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{11}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that if you change `\begin{array}{11}` (number one) to `\begin{array}{l}` (lowercase letter L) it will work.

Comment: You're getting "a correct output" for two reasons. First, LaTeX automatically replaces invalid column specifiers -- here: `1` ("one") -- with `c` ("center"). Second, because your arrays only have 1 column, `\begin{array}{cc}` behaves just like `\begin{array}{c}`, i.e., the "empty" second column is ignored. That's why you're getting "a correct output".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is solved by [Phelype Oleinik's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) comment, however with use of the package `amsmath` your equation can be written as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
C_1 = \{\beta_{1,1}, \beta_{2,1}\}
    = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

¸
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Oleinik and Zarko. Both of the solutions work. The amsmath is a neat one to read. I have never used amsmath package. Zarko can you refer me a guide on it.

Comment: @Er.ABCool, `amsmath` is a package for "advance" math settings. it is part of every latex distribution.  documentation you can find in your latext installation or on the ctan https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath?lang=en. for math seting is also worth to read https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics.